# Задан текст, нужно напечатать слова отличные от последнего и удовлетворяющие свойству: в слове встречается буква вводимая с клавиатуры

Tags: c++

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include <iostream>

#include <string>

#include <vector>

int main()

{

//  std::string i;

    std::vector<std::string> arr;

    //std::cout << "vvedite bykdBy:";

    //std::cin >> i;

    std::string word;

    while (std::cin >> word)

        arr.push_back(word);

    std::size_t result = word.find('i');

    if (result != std::string::npos)

        std::cout << word << '\n';

    //вывод слов 

    for (auto x : arr) {

        if (x != arr.back())

            std::cout << x << std::endl;

    }

    std::cin.get();

    return 0;

}

//ctrlz
```

Comment: Сформулируйте вашу проблему.

Comment: Помогите соединить эти 2 условия до рабочего состояния.

Comment: отличные от последнего введённого или последнего выведенного?

Comment: Последнее введенное в строку слово

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Запоминаем только слова с нужной буквой, и выводим только несовпадающие с последним введенным.

```
int main() {
    std::vector<std::string> arr;
    //std::cout << "vvedite bykdBy:";
    //std::cin >> i;
    std::string word, last;
    while (std::cin >> word) {
        last = word;
        if (word.find('i') != string::npos)
            arr.push_back(word);
        }
    for (auto x : arr) {
        if (x != last)
            std::cout << x << std::endl;
        }
    }
```